# Sequelize migration queryInterface.removeColum fails to work

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I created a migration file to add a column as an `up` and then delete it under `down`.

Here's the migration file code:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
    queryInterface.addColumn('Books', 'Rating', {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.ENUM('like', 'dislike'),
    }),

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    queryInterface.removeColumn('Books', 'Rating');
  },
};
```

When I ran it for the first time using `db:migrate`, it successfully added the column but when I did a `db:migrate:undo:all` and then ran the migrations again, it threw me an error sqying

```
======= 20180211100937-AddedRatingIntoBooks: migrating 
======= 2018-02-11 15:42:46.076 IST 
[64531] ERROR:  type "enum_Books_Rating" already exists 2018-02-11 15:42:46.076 IST 
[64531] STATEMENT:  CREATE TYPE "public"."enum_Books_Rating" AS ENUM('like', 'dislike');
ALTER TABLE "public"."Boo ks" ADD COLUMN "Rating" "public"."enum_Books_Rating";

    ERROR: type "enum_Books_Rating" already exists
```

The issue is still live [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2554).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sequelize creates TYPES for each of the enum you define, which you can find [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/224f329b9ee55a5f9789d002683dd68d5ddc78aa/lib/dialects/postgres/query-generator.js#L790)

The name of the ENUM type is the concatenation of "enum", the table name, and the column name in snake casing. (`enum_Books_Rating` here)

To create migrations for `ENUM`, you have to modify your down function like so:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
    queryInterface.addColumn('Books', 'Rating', {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.ENUM('like', 'dislike')
  }),

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>  
    queryInterface.removeColumn('Books', 'Rating')
      .then(() => queryInterface.sequelize.query('DROP TYPE "enum_Books_Rating";'));
  };
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a note - If the error exists before one uses this code, he or she needs to go execute `DROP TYPE enum_tableName_attributeName` at the database first before he runs any kind of up or down migrations.